# Declare variable in makefile using the bash for

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to declare a variable using a `for` from `bash` in a makefile. That's what I tried:

```
SRCS="path/to/foo.c path/to/boo.c path/to/bar.c"
OBJS=$(for file in $SRCS; do TEMP="$TEMP $(basename $file .c).o"; done; echo $TEMP)
```

This command:

```
for file in $SRCS; do TEMP="$TEMP $(basename $file .c).o"; done
```

works on bash when echoing `TEMP`. But `OBJS` in makefile is empty. What am I missing here?

Desired output:

```
foo.o boo.o bar.o
```

Comment: How do you plan to use the variables? Using the internal macro `$%` to get `foo.o` when the recipe is applied to `foo.c` is probably cleaner than trying to build the lists yourself.

Comment: This way: `gcc -shared -lm -o output $(OBJS)`

Comment: If you are using GNU `make`, then `OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))` might be what you want.

Comment: OP was looking to strip the path name as well, so it would be `OBJS := $(notdir $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))` or `$(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there's better ways to do this without using bash's for.  You could use the make constructs to generate these lists.   See the documentation on `$(notdir)`, `$(addprefix...)` and `$(addsuffix ...)`

However, to answer your question on this particular example:

First, you are putting quotes around sources.  Make does not interpret quotes as special characters, and thus `SRCS` will expand to  `"path/to/foo.c path/to/boo.c path/to/bar.c"` (including the quotes).  This will mess up your for loop later on.

The next thing is the reference to `$SRCS` -- make will interpret this as `$S` followed by the literal `RCS` (which is not what you want).   You have to use braces around multi0letter variables in bash as so -- `$(SRCS)`

Next, `TEMP=$TEMP...`.   When make sees `$TEMP`, it will immediately attempt to expand it.   Because `TEMP` is not set to anything in the make context, it will expand to a null string -- this is before it invokes the bash shell...   What you wanted to do in this case is use `$$TEMP`, which make will expand to `$TEMP`.

The following does what you want: note the `$(info)` lines are just for debugging.

```
SRCS:=path/to/foo.c path/to/boo.c path/to/bar.c
OBJS:=$(shell for file in $(SRCS); do TEMP="$$TEMP $$(basename $$file .c).o"; done; echo $$TEMP)
$(info for file in $(SRCS); do TEMP="$$TEMP $$(basename $$file .c).o"; done; echo $$TEMP)    
$(info OBJS=$(OBJS))
```

If you wanted to do this in makefile without bash or sh, you might try:

```
OBJS:=$(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o))
```

Note: this is gnu-make specific syntax and may not work on other makes.